# Is it recommend to use Tor browser to buy things online?

Tags: browsers

I know that you'll have the same identity (IP) on the same site but since it's not your own IP (in another word you're connecting the site through other device) is it safe (recommend) to buy things online through Tor?

Comment: It's not generally *unsafe* but often it simply won't work, most online payment systems have blacklisted Tor IP addresses meaning you wouldn't be able to use Tor anyway.